# Did anybody implement RNNDROP in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Dropout as a regularizer is well implemented in tensorflow. That includes dropout between layers in RNNs. Did anybody implement **dropout on the states between timesteps** in RNNs, possibly as in [RNNDROP](http://mind.dgist.ac.kr/files/Conference/asru2015.pdf) or otherwise?